# Cucumber-TestNG: "The type gherkin.events.PickleEvent cannot be resolved" error when trying to usepickleEvent.getPickleEvent()

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I moved from info-cukes to io-cucumber recently and trying to run each Scenario as individual test. I tried using testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleEvent.getPickleEvent()). But pickleEvent.getPickleEvent() is getting highlighted with the error "The type gherkin.events.PickleEvent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class file"

Below shown are the dependencies I have added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>          
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below shown is my TestRunner class:

```
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import io.cucumber.testng.PickleEventWrapper;
//import gherkin.events.PickleEvent;

import io.cucumber.gherkin.pickles.PickleCompiler;

@CucumberOptions(
        features="<Features_Package_path>"
        ,glue= {"com.crm.bdd.stepdefinitions"}
        ,monochrome = true
        ,dryRun = false
        ,strict = true
        ,tags = {"@RegressionTest", "~@Ignore"}                                                         ,plugin = "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json"
)

public class RegressionTestRunner {

    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClasss() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void scenario(PickleEventWrapper pickleEvent, CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Throwable {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleEvent.getPickleEvent());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }

}
```

NOTE: I played around with multiple versions of cucumber-gherkin, gherkin and all other dependencies. I believe gherkin jar is supposed to contain gherkin.events package. But I couldn't find it in any of the versions which I tried. When I perform "import gherkin.events.PickleEvent;", the error disappears. But the imported gherkin.events.PickleEvent remains unresolved, since that is not found under gherkin jar.

Comment: You don't need most of those dependencies. Might be good to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and start from scratch with a [10-minute tutorial](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/).

Comment: And I doubt your version of Extent is compatible with the latest Cucumber.

Comment: Thanks for your response @M.P.Korstanje. Unfortunately I don't see any details on TestRunner class in that 10 mins tutorial. Also ExtentReportUtil class is a util class which I have created. 4.0.6 is the Extent Report version I am using

Comment: If you don't make your problem smaller first you can't solve it.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje I have tried removing unwanted dependencies and unwanted lines of code from TestRunner class. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Not really. Start from scratch. Make a small thing work, then add more complexity - repeat until you find the change that reproduces your problem. It's a skill you have to learn. Takes time, but it is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Use latest version of dependencies for io.cucumber.cucumber-java and cucumber-testng. (I have used version 6.10.2 for both)

Then try the code snippet instead of ***PickleEventWrapper*** and ***CucumberFeatureWrapper***

```
@Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "scenarios")
public void scenario(PickleWrapper pickleWrapper, FeatureWrapper featureWrapper) throws Throwable {
    testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleWrapper.getPickle());
}
```

It should work. I had the same issue and this resolved my problem. Give it a try.